# Use UDP without specifc port for Multicast

Tags: python, networking, udp, multicast

IP multicast gives you the ability to send a single packet, which is picked up by multiple interfaces if they are subscribed to that multicast. If I understand it correctly.

Now if I want to use UDP, in combination with IP multicast, I am obligated to assign a port to listen to. But now I understand that I only receive UDP packets on a multicast specifically sent to that port. But I would like to intercept all UDP packets send to a certain multicast IP address, regardless of the port and receive them at my single socket.

Is something like this possible?

Preferably accompanied by a python example, if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible using the BSD socket API (which is roughly the API Python exposes in its `socket` module) - except by creating 2 ** 16 - 1 sockets and using them to bind to all ports.

It's possible using lower-level interfaces such as the [TUN/TAP system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) offered by Linux.

Comment: In addition to what @Jean wrote, for sending a multicast packet, you do not have to be bind ("assign") to the port number designated for multicast traffic. The application needs to bind to the port, only if it wants to receive data destined for that port.

Comment: And in addition to what @ManojPandey wrote, it isn't necessary for the sender to join the multicast group either.